# Symfony bundle config

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, bundle

I'm building my first symfony bundle and for some reason I can't get configuration to work.

Configuration.php

```
..........
$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('custom.yml');
..........
```

custom.yml

```
bd_config:
 version: 2
```

ConfigExtension.php

```
 $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('bd_config');


        $rootNode->
          children()
            ->integerNode('version')->end()
          ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
```

And I get this error

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "bd_config" (in /Library/WebServer/symfony/src/BD/ConfigBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/custom.yml). Looked for namespace "bd_config", found none

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a naming convention on using bundle configs. Your config root have to be in the following format:

```
vendor_bundle
```

Where if your bundle name is in camel case and consists of more than one word (apart from Bundle and vendor name), then it contains further _ signs. Eg: `CompanySuperSymfonyBundle` will be `company_super_symfony`.

After that, you can set your configuration:

```
company_super_symfony:
    version: 100
```

Treebuilder:

```
$rootNode->
      children()
        ->integerNode('version')->end()
      ->end();
```

You don't have to load anything using the Loader, but you have to add your config as container parameter:

```
$container->setParameter('version', $config['version']);
```

And then, in your controller:

```
... = $this->container->getParameter('version');
```

Comment: My bundle name is BDConfigBundle so bd_config in that case is correct. Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried using b_d_config as namespace in your config? Because of the camel case, it might be good. Apart from that try to set the root name to `config` instead of `bd_config`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're doing it wrong :).

1. your yml is invalid (1 space indent)
2. the `Configuration.php` should build the tree (not the extension)
3. the `*Extension.php` loads the resources (not the tree)

Maybe it works then, but I don't know if `BDConfigBundle` is `b_d_config` in yml. I would use `BdConfig` as bundlename and `bd_config` as yml root.

Then I would import your yml in `config.yml`:

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: custom.yml }
```

BdConfigStoreExtension.php

```
class BdConfigStoreExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $bdConfigNode = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ;).